# in ionic3, page.module.ts file does not created

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic. I'm trying to make new project using ionic3. 
my problem is when I type 'ionic g page pagename', only 'pagename.html', 'pagename.scss', 'pagename.ts' are created. no 'pagename.module.ts'

I have two projects using ionic, but only in one project that command does not create module.ts file. 
in the other project, it works.

if you know why, please tell me.

this is my ionic version.

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.12
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.5.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v8.1.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b 
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 5.0.3
```

Comment: Why do you expect `pagename.module.ts` to be created?

Comment: @Clonkex thanks for comment! I heard that for lazy loading it is needed.

Comment: Well in all honesty I don't know Iconic at all, I was just going over some questions and wondered if maybe you were expecting something that will never happen. I expect someone that knows Ionic will be able to help you soon :)

Comment: @Clonkex I expect too :) thanks for showing interest

Answer (score 1):

Default lazy loading was removed for CLI version you installed, but CLI team will be adding the functionality back.

[See here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1105)